# Compute difference in lon / lat when moving at angle

Tags: distance, angles, haversine

I have the following problem: I have been given an origin as a lon / lat pair, a distance in kilometers and an angle on the ground, relative to the cardinal directions. My goal is to compute the destination (as a lon / lat pair) which is reached after moving in the direction given by the angle for the given distance.

How might I go about computing the destination? Is there a closed formula?

Comment: Kilometres are only really calculatable in a projected coordinate system, your input and output are geographic.. your workflow would have to be project input into metres, calculate a new point from kilometre offset to generate the destination in projected coordinates and project the destination to geographic.. for this you will need software, what GIS software or API do you have available? The next *real* challenge is finding a projected coordinate system that doesn't distort bearings too much - and *that* is a new question unto itself... how accurate does this need to be?

Comment: Well, I am using `pyqgis`. The distance is a little less than 300 kilometers, but I would have thought that this is a well posed problem: After all there should only be one great circle containing the origin and having the required (local) degree should't it?

Comment: @hfhc2 A great circle is on a sphere. The earth is better modeled as an ellipsoid which complicates the equations. See [geodetic problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#Geodetic_problems) section in Wikipedia. How accurate does the target coordinate need to be?

Comment: OK, true. I think a spheric model is quite sufficient for me at this point.

Comment: Remember that great circles on a spherical earth have continually changing Azimuth (direction relative to true north), except for those through the poles or around the equator.  For very short distances, this can be ignored, but at 300 km along the surface, this would make a difference, so you need to be clear about what you mean by azimuth. See - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth#/media/File:Bearing_and_azimuth_along_the_geodesic.png

Comment: Just a suggestion, but, perhaps you could construct a line from your start point with the given bearing and arbitrary length, say 1 minute (which is approximately a nautical mile around the equator), project the line to an appropriate UTM Zone and construct an extension point for your destination using the angle start->end of the arbitrary line.. not perfect by any stretch but it should be reasonably close up to ~100km. To do this you will need software, as I said before, and some scripting prowess (I know of no out-of-the-box tool for this, you'll have to script it).

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem in spherical geometry, like all midshipmen needed to learn in 17th century ;>)

This site has actual calculating scripts, but also shows the formulae, with explanations if you want to calculate yourself.

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

See the section - "Destination point given distance and bearing from start point"